# I am kinda new to the pytorch, now struggling with a classification problem

Tags: pytorch, classification

I built a very simple structure

```
class classifier (nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.classify = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(166,80),
        nn.Tanh(),
        nn.Linear(80,40),
        nn.Tanh(),
        nn.Linear(40,1),
        nn.Softmax()
    )
def forward (self, x):
    pred = self.classify(x)
    return pred
model = classifier()
```

The loss function and optimizer are defined as

```
criteria = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
iteration = 1000
learning_rate = 0.1
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
```

and here is the training and evaluation section

```
for epoch in range (iteration):
  model.train()
  y_pred = model(x_train)
  loss = criteria(y_pred,y_train)
  optimizer.zero_grad()
  loss.backward()
  optimizer.step()


  model.eval()
  with torch.inference_mode():
      test_pred = model(x_test)
      test_loss = criteria(test_pred, y_test)

  if epoch % 100 == 0:
      print(loss)
      print(test_loss)
```

I received the same loss values, and by debugging, I found that the weights were not being updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the network architecture: you are using a `Softmax` layer on a single valued output at the end. As per the definition of the softmax function, for a output vector `x`, we have, for index `i`:

```
softmax(x_i) = e^{x_i} / sum_j (e^{x_j})
```

Here, you only have a single valued output. Due to this, the output of your neural network is always 1, irrespective of the inputs or the weights. To fix this, remove the `Softmax` layer at the end. An activation function like `Sigmoid` might be more appropriate, and in fact you are already applying this when using the `BCEWithLogitsLoss`.

Comment: Thanks! That surely solves the zero gradient and constant loss problem. But I want the class ID as the output of the network (ex, 1,2,3,4). By removing the Softmax activation function, the current outputs are in decimal forms rather than int. I am sure it is another kind of problem, and I will try to solve it by myself. But I would really appreciate some more hints on this!

Comment: @Mercury460 Are you doing a multiclass classification problem? That is, do you have a fixed number of classes (say 10), and you need to classify from amongst those classes?

Comment: Yes, I have tagged my datasets by 4 classes

Comment: @Mercury460 Then the typical way to do it would be to have a four dimensional output, one per class, and then applying softmax on it at the end to get a probability distribution across the four classes. In this case a loss like CrossEntropyLoss might be more appropriate. [This](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html) might help.

Comment: I think your info is more than enough for me to move forward, millions of thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here

```py
y_pred = model(x_train)
  loss = criteria(y_pred,y_train)
  optimizer.zero_grad()
  loss.backward()
  optimizer.step()
```

after `loss` is calculated, you are clearing the gradients by doing `optimizer.zero_grad()`

the ideal case should be:

```py
  optimizer.zero_grad()
  y_pred = model(x_train)
  loss = criteria(y_pred,y_train)
  loss.backward()
  optimizer.step()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but the problem still exists after I change the sequence

Comment: how are you checking the weights ?

Comment: I am running it step by step to check the parameters passed to the optimizer in every loop. And the loss is still not changing.

Comment: you are not passing parameters in the optimizer in loop. parameters should be passed only once in the optimizer.

Comment: Sorry it should be my problem of word choice. I checked the parameter branch in optimizer for the first three loops

Comment: try to use: `loss = criteria(y_pred,y_train) * 10000` and see if weights are changing.

Comment: I see, u r worrying about the acuuracy and the step length of each training loop？

Comment: original loss might be too small to have any significant change in the parameters.

Comment: Well... that's not the case, my original was round 0.3, but after multiplying it by 10000 it still does not work. Since I have checked the structure several times with the official example, I am considering whether it is my input data to blame

Comment: This should not matter, since the gradients are only calculated in the `loss.backward()` step.